# What design of these two works best?

Tags: sql, database, jpa, orm

I have  the following entity structure  Ads ( Land  ( Agricultural, Construction) , Spaces ( Condo, Ind_Space, Office)   ) .   I'm not sure whether to make the foreign keys part of the parent and reference the child ( ads would have to also have a trigger that ensure that one and only one coumn is NOT NULL) or the other way around ( I hear this is how you imlplement polymorphism in rdbms) and have in  tables Construction and Agricultural  a FK pointing to land, and land a FK pointing to ads. I plan on using  JPA so the first implementation seems a little easier  to implement and better  when it comes to performance but higher memory cost .  I'm interested on how it would stack up against the other solution and how you think it;s best to proceed when you have this type of entity model. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Have i not been clear somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a OneToMany, then you need to foreign key in the target (or use a join table).

If it is a ManyToOne, then you need to foreign key in the source.

If it is a OneToOne, then you can use either.  Most OO people prefer putting the foreign key in the source, some database people prefer the target.  Personally I think putting it in the source is best (it can then get a cache hit, and models Java better).  If your relationship is bi-directional, then you will be using both solutions anyway.